# C++ Perform calculations on a huge array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was asked a question for a job interview and I did not know the correct answer....

The question was:

If you have an array of 10 000 000 ints between 1 and 100, determine (efficiently) how many pairs of these ints sum up to 150 or less.

I don't know how to do this without a loop within a loop, but that is not very efficient.

Does anyone please have some pointers for me?

Comment: Since the integers are all between 1 and 100, we can very cheaply make one pass through the array just to count the number of 1's, the number of 2's and so on. From then, we're only manipulating 100 numbers instead of 10,000,000. (Assuming by 'pairs' you mean pairs anywhere in the array. Otherwise, it's even easier.)

Comment: Pairs meaning they have to be next to one another? Basically you want to sum up 5,000,000 int pairs?

Comment: I took pairs to mean any two within the array, as opposed to, say, any number of addends.

Comment: The question is incomplete. It does not specify whether it "consumes" numbers or not. As in, if you use a number to pair it up with one, can you then use the same number again to pair it up with another? If not, you need to first design an algorithm to determine efficient pairing!

Comment: Your first response should have been "what do you mean by a pair"? I wouldn't be surprised if this question was intentionally vague to see how you react to vague specifications.

Answer (score 7):

One way is by creating a smaller array of 100 elements.  Loop through the 10,000,000 elements and count how many of each.  Store the counter in the 100 element array.

```
    // create an array counter of 101 elements and set every element to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
          counter[input[i]]++;
    }
```

then do a second loop j from 1 to 100.  inside that, have a loop k from 1 to min(150-j,j).  if k!=j, add counter[j]*counter[k].  if k=j, add (counter[j]-1)*counter[j].

the total sum is your result.

Your total run time is bounded on the top by 10,000,000 + 100*100 = 10,010,000 (it's actually smaller than this).

This is a lot faster than (10,000,000)^2, which is 100,000,000,000,000.

Of course, you have to give up 101 int space in memory.

Delete counter when you're done.

Note also (as pointed out in the discussion below) that this is assuming that order matters.  If order doesn't matter, just divide the result by 2.

Comment: I would imagine the OP would get a rap for using `new` for a compile-time known 100-sized array. Just a point. Plus you have to subtract one from `input[i]` or make the array one bigger than it has to be.

Comment: good point.  one advantage of new is of course, if that size changes later, there is no issue with blowing up the stack.  i.e. if the guy who wrote this piece of code quit, a new programmer joins, and the requirement changes, what happens?  oh yea, -1 is good catch!

Comment: I'd suggest a vector if you really cared, but a new person should be automatically wary when changing the size of an array to be really big.

Comment: that could work, too, but then it comes with an overhead and assumes you have stl (or some library with vector).  it really depends on the situation.  bottom line is that there's a million ways to do this.  there is probably a clever way to do it with less temporary memory requirement if you ponder the problem for awhile.

Comment: If the size can change, you will have to rewrite the program anyway. But, until it becomes that big, I'd rather see automatic storage used.

Comment: @melpomene, I did mention to delete the counter when you're done, so there's no memory leak.  new zeros on some runtimes in debug mode.  I don't know of any that zeros in release mode.  Anyway, this his a holy war that we should reserve for a different forum.  new/int[100]/vector is not the point of the question, but it's an interesting discussion, though.  That code is meant to be pseudo, by the way.  That it looks kinda like C++ reflects my bias.

Comment: AFAIK, `new` doesn't touch POD. `new()` would value-initialize it.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the new for everyone who has gripes with it.  now, translate it into whatever language you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.. David, yes, I also assumed any pairs within the array, not sequential pairs. @Mahmoud, appologies, my assumption here was that numbers are NOT consumed (although I didn't actually even think about it until you mentioned it!) thang, thank you, I will certainly take a look at that....

Comment: ps, sorry, its my first post here and I can't figure out how to do a new line.... (I know, off topic). I tried ctrl + enter, but it still submits...

Comment: I think this solution is not correct. Consider this: all input numbers happen to be `1`. If identical numbers are permitted in pairs (and there is no reason to believe why not), then correct answer should be `1000000*(1000000-1)/2`. I do not believe that this solution will give this result (actually I checked that it will return `0`, which is just totally wrong).

Comment: @mvp, the solution actually would return 10000000*(10000000-1).  check again.  i think the correct answer for that should be 10000000*(10000000-1).  this is because there are 10000000 of the number 1.  each one can match with every other one but itself (because this wouldn't be a pair), so the result is 10000000*(10000000-1).  i am assuming order matters.  if order matters, divide everything by 2.

Comment: Ok, I agree as long as you divide it by 2 :-)

Comment: What if the numbers can be between 1 and 1000, and add up to 1500? I think my solution would be linear, whereas yours is quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

first, I would sort the array. Then you start a single pass through the sorted array. You get the single value n in that cell and find the correspondent lowest value that is still allowed (e.g. for 15 it is 135). Now you find the index of this value in the array and that's the amount of pairs for n. Sum up all these and you have (if my mind is working correctly) counted each pair twice, so if you divide the sum by 2, you have the correct number.

The solution should be O(n log n) compared to the trivial one, which is O(n^2)

Comment: Of course the next question is: How do you sort 10 million integers?

Comment: Aside from the fact `135` is out of range, how do you find the index of `135`? Linear search, binary?

Comment: STL sort & find. O(log n) for finding and O(n log n) for searching.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of questions always require a mixture of mathematical insight and efficient programming. They don't want brute force.

### First Insight

Numbers can be grouped according to how they will pair with other groups.

Putting them into:

```
1 - 50 | 51 - 75 | 76 - 100
  A    |    B    |    C
```

- Group `A` can pair with anything.
- Group `B` can pair with `A` and `B`, and `possibly` `C`
- Group `C` can pair with `A` and `possibly` `B`, but not `C`

The `possibly` is where we need some more insight.

### Second Insight

For each number in B we need to check how many numbers there are up to its complement with 150. For example, with `62` from group `B` we want to know from group `C` how many numbers are less than or equal to `88`.

For each number in `C` we add up the tallies up to it, e.g. tallies for 76, 77, 78, ..., 88. This is known mathematically as the partial sum.

In the standard library there is a function which produces a [`partial_sum`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/partial_sum/)

```
vector<int> tallies(25); // this is room for the tallies from C
vector<int> partial_sums(25);

partial_sum(tallies.begin(), tallies.end(), partial_sums.begin());
```

Symmetry means this sum only needs to be done for one group.

### Third (much later) insight

Calculating the totals for group `A` and `B` can be done using `partial_sum`, too. So rather than only calculating for group `C`, and having to track the totals some other way, just store the totals for each number from 1 to 100, and then create the partial_sum over the whole thing. `partial_sums[50]` will give you the amount of numbers less than or equal to 50, partial_sums[75] those less than or equal to 75, and partial_sums[100] should be 10 million, i.e. all the numbers less than or equal to 100.

Finally we can calculate the combinations from `B` and `C`. We want to add together all the multiples of totals for 50 and 100, 51 and 99, 52 and 98, etc. we can do this by iterating through the tallies from 50 to 75 and the partial_sums from 100 to 75. There is a standard library function [`inner_product`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/inner_product/) which can handle this.

This seems quite linear to me.

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 100);

vector<int> tallies(100);
for(int i=0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    tallies[dis(gen)]++;
}

vector<int> partial_sums(100);
partial_sum(tallies.begin(), tallies.end(), partial_sums.begin());

int A = partial_sums[50];
int AB = partial_sums[75];
int ABC = partial_sums[100]; 
int B = AB - A;
int C = ABC - AB;

int A_match = A * ABC;
int B_match = B * B;
int C_match = inner_product(&tallies[50], &tallies[75],
                            partial_sums.rend(), 0);
```